# Perl subroutine running more slowly with each successive call

Tags: perl, benchmarking

I have a strange problem where I call the same subroutine several times in succession, processing the same data, and my code takes successively longer with each call.  My program is doing some matrix mathematics, but I am asking a more general question here to see if anyone has the same issue, so I don't know if the specifics are important.  Below is code at the very bottom of my main program loop.

```
use Time::HiRes qw (gettimeofday);

($lus2_sec,$lus2_usec) = gettimeofday();
@blah_LU_v2 = invert_LU_v2(@zmatrix);
($lue2_sec,$lue2_usec) = gettimeofday();
$lu2_elapsed = sprintf("%.3f", ($lue2_sec+($lue2_usec/1000000))-($lus2_sec+($lus2_usec/1000000)));
syswrite STDOUT, "$lu2_elapsed seconds\n";

($lus2_sec,$lus2_usec) = gettimeofday();
@blah_LU_v2 = invert_LU_v2(@zmatrix);
($lue2_sec,$lue2_usec) = gettimeofday();
$lu2_elapsed = sprintf("%.3f", ($lue2_sec+($lue2_usec/1000000))-($lus2_sec+($lus2_usec/1000000)));
syswrite STDOUT, "$lu2_elapsed seconds\n";
```

Each subroutine operates on the same @zmatrix data, which it does not change.  I get the exact same answer from each subroutine call (verified earlier), so I know it's not screwing up the input data.  The subroutine is also a simple single threaded structure, and this is being run on an idle 12-core workstation with 96GB of RAM.  There should be no disk swapping or CPU issue since this machine has more than enough power to handle this relatively small matrix.  However, the output of the program results in something like this (running five successive calls of the subroutine, obviously):

```
96.485 seconds
99.116 seconds
100.036 seconds
100.615 seconds
101.494 seconds
```

The subroutine keeps getting a little slower for as many tests as I've run.  If I terminate and relaunch the program from the command line, it will start out at around 96 seconds and then slow down from there every single time.  Why would it be slowing down like this?

The subroutine with the issue is shown below.  Note that I've now used NYTProf to nail down the time increase to calls of Math::Complex::_multiply and _minus.  Each time I call the invert_LU_v2 subroutine, it makes the same number of calls to Math::Complex, but they take a few % longer on subsequent calls of invert_LU_v2.  Please also feel free to critique my code and let me know what else I'm doing wrong.  I am a beginner, have no training, and don't really know what I'm doing.

```
sub invert_LU_v2 {
    my(@junk) = (@_);
    my @matrix_local;
    my @matrix_L;
    my @matrix_B;
    my @matrix_inverse;

    my $tt;
    my $row;
    my $col;
    my $temp;
    my $reduced;
    my $normalize = 1;
    my $multiplier = 1;
    my $dimension = @junk - 1;

    for($row=1;$row<=$dimension;$row++){
        for($col=1;$col<=$dimension;$col++){
            $matrix_local[$row][$col]=$junk[$row][$col];
        }
    }

    for($row=1;$row<=$dimension;$row++){
        for($col=1;$col<=$dimension;$col++){
            if($row==$col){$matrix_L[$row][$col] = 1;$matrix_B[$row][$col] = 1;}
            else {$matrix_L[$row][$col] = 0;$matrix_B[$row][$col] = 0;}
        }
    }

    for($row=1;$row<=$dimension;$row++){

        $normalize = $matrix_local[$row][$row];
        $matrix_L[$row][$row] = $normalize;             
        for($col=1;$col<=$dimension;$col++){
            $matrix_local[$row][$col] /= $normalize;
        }

        for($temp=$row+1;$temp<=$dimension;$temp++){
            if(($temp != $row) && (abs($matrix_local[$temp][$row]) != 0)){
                $multiplier = $matrix_local[$temp][$row];
                $matrix_L[$temp][$row] = $multiplier;
                for($col=$row;$col<=$dimension;$col++){
                    $reduced = $matrix_local[$temp][$col] - $matrix_local[$row][$col]*$multiplier;
                    $matrix_local[$temp][$col] = $reduced;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    my @y_intermediate;

    for($col=1;$col<=$dimension;$col++){$y_intermediate[1][$col] = $matrix_B[1][$col]/$matrix_L[1][1]}

    for($col=1;$col<=$dimension;$col++){
        for($row=2;$row<=$dimension;$row++){
            $y_intermediate[$row][$col] = $matrix_B[$row][$col];
            for($tt=1;$tt<=($row-1);$tt++){$y_intermediate[$row][$col] -= ($matrix_L[$row][$tt]*$y_intermediate[$tt][$col])}
            $y_intermediate[$row][$col] /= $matrix_L[$row][$row];
        }
    }

    for($col=1;$col<=$dimension;$col++){$matrix_inverse[$dimension][$col] = $y_intermediate[$dimension][$col]/$matrix_local[$dimension][$dimension]}

    for($col=1;$col<=$dimension;$col++){
        for($row=($dimension-1);$row>=1;$row--){
            $matrix_inverse[$row][$col] = $y_intermediate[$row][$col];
            for($tt=($row+1);$tt<=$dimension;$tt++){$matrix_inverse[$row][$col] -= ($matrix_local[$row][$tt]*$matrix_inverse[$tt][$col])}
            $matrix_inverse[$row][$col] /= $matrix_local[$row][$row];
        }
    }

    return(@matrix_inverse);
}
```

Comment: Any chance there's a variable somewhere else that is being filled up and thus slowing down the overall program?

Comment: I've looked, and the only other variables are defined locally in other subroutines or defined globally once at the very beginning and then never touched again.  I even tried to 'undef' the @blah_LU_v2 matrix between each call, and it did no good.

Comment: Why don't you post the `invert_LU_v2` implementation?

Comment: if you are not having 'use strict;' and 'use warnings;' in your code, you're creating a lot of headache for yourself. there is a memory leak in your code and using the two pragmas can be the first step to detect it.

Comment: I have both use strict and use warnings in my code.  There are no issues flagged by either.

Comment: There are a lot of things that could do this, though they mostly boil down to "your sub has a side effect".  Absent the definition of the sub, we won't be able to give you more precise help.

Comment: I have now included the problematic subroutine in the description.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Benchmark](http://perldoc.perl.org/Benchmark.html) to do benchmarks :-)

Maybe the problem not in your program but in your measurment?

Use [Devel::NYTProf](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Devel-NYTProf/lib/Devel/NYTProf.pm) for debug. It will show you a lot of useful info, timings, etc.

Comment: NYTProf is awesome.  It really shows you where your time is being spent.

Comment: I tried the Benchmark module and the results match up with the times from my Time::Hires method.  I have not yet tried NYTProf, but I will do so next.  Thanks for the advice!

Comment: NYTProf indeed is awesome.  It shows that each call of the subroutine has the exact same number of 'calculations', as expected.  The additional time spent in my subroutine when called a second time is concentrated in Math::Complex::_multiply and Math::Complex::_minus.  This accounts for over 95% of the time difference.  I've included my sub in the main question above, but can anything in there cause the issue or is this a problem with Math::Complex?

Comment: I think it is Math::Complex or somewhere in your code you maintain a reference to a variable and it is not getting cleared automatically. Try to weaken your variables, http://perldoc.perl.org/Scalar/Util.html

Comment: First guess is to weaken @junk

Comment: Try NYTProf, and if it the same, contact the module author.